# Meaning of “supra se servitium”

Tags: idiom, latin-to-english-translation, swedish

#### Background

In the TV series [Fallet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallet_(TV_series)), some of the upper class of the fictional town of Norbacka use the phrase

> supra se servitium

as a sort of salutation. Its meaning is never elaborated upon.

#### My attempt

I tried and failed to understand this phrase with my rusty Latin:

- *[supra](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/supra#Latin)* means *over, before,* or similar and takes the accusative.
- *[se](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/se#Latin)* is the reflexive pronoun in the accusative or ablative, i.e., roughly *himself, herself,* etc.
- *[servitium](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/servitium#Noun)* means *servitude* or *servantry* and is in the nominative or accusative case.

My ideas so far are:

- The object of *supra* is *se.* This would yield a meaning like

  > servitude over oneself

  which I fail to make sense of in this context (or any other).
- The object of *supra* is *servitium.* This would yield something like

  > over the servitude/servantry

  which makes more sense, but leaves the *se* dangling.
- It is false Latin whose intended meaning may be appreciated with some knowledge of Swedish. This would be consistent insofar as the entire town of Norbacka is oozing with incompetence.

#### Question

What’s the meaning or intended meaning of this phrase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect it means

> [Put] service above [attending to] oneself.

[I posted this as a comment, because it was just a guess, but two people have asked me to post it as an answer].

Answer (score 6):

There was a reference to Rotary in one of the early episodes. Rotary International’s motto is “Service Above Self.”  Possible connection?

Answer (score 2):

It's a fake military motto, probably from their time in service (lumpen).
It would mean something similar to "The service (of others) before oneself" or "Put service above yourself".